# POST not working on python flask app with vue frontend (preflight)

Tags: python-3.x, api, vue.js, nuxt.js, flask-restful

I'm having trouble with getting CORS to work with my setup. I have a python_flask on the backend and a vue nuxt app on the frontend. My GET work in the frontend but each time I try to post I get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/Animals' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js?b50d:178 POST http://localhost:5000/api/Animals net::ERR_FAILED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js?0a06:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js?0a06:86
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
addNewAnimalForm @ AddAnimalForm.vue?c82c:50
click @ AddAnimalForm.vue?d1a7:68
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2175
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
AddAnimalForm.vue?c82c:53 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at eval (AddAnimalForm.vue?c82c:53)
```

This is my app file in python:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from resources.Animal import AnimalResource
from resources.Add import AddResource

api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
CORS(api_bp, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
api = Api(api_bp)

# Routes

api.add_resource(AnimalResource, '/Animal')
api.add_resource(AddResource, '/Add')
```

This is the frontend method that posts:

```
  methods: {
    addNewAnimalForm () {
      this.$axios.post('/Animals', { 'species_name': this.animalSearch })
        .then((Response) => {})
        .catch((err) => {
          this.errors = err
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: please show the vue method that's posting the data.

Comment: have updated with post on on frontend

Comment: thanks. Your original error looks like it's to do with how you're handling the error from your axios post. Have you set up 'errors' in your vue data?

Comment: ah thanks, yes you're right I didn't have error in my data! I have added that and changed it to equal err for now (updated in the question), I'm only getting the preflight error now. This request works in Postman, when i put the species_name in the body as an object.

Comment: Postman doesn't need to comply with CORS, so as you say the reason the browser is having trouble now is CORS, I've never used python flask so not sure what could be causing the CORS problem. I did notice you've got vue on port 3000 and the API on 5000. If your running vue via vue cli in HMR dev mode, you could try making sure the dev server proxies API requests to 5000.